# how can I turn a set of csv lines into xml?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Is there a way to take a spreadsheet and turn it into xml file below?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfBusiness xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Business>
    <Name>Company Name 1</Name>
    <AddressList>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine>123 Main St.</AddressLine>
      </Address>
    </AddressList>
  </Business>
  <Business>
    <Name>Company Name 2</Name>
    <AddressList>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine>1 Elm St.</AddressLine>
      </Address>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine>2 Elm St.</AddressLine>
      </Address>
    </AddressList>
  </Business>
</ArrayOfBusiness>
```

Comment: Of course there isn't. CSV is a comma separated, while XML is hierarchical. There's no 1 to 1 mapping possible. You're gonna need something to perform the conversion and this something needs to understand both formats so don't expect miracles.

Comment: 2nded for xslt, this data looks pretty flat. But xslt is a pain to work with, personally i'd use linqpad and dump this out to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put this in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and it did what you needed. If you've never used LinqPad... well now's a great time to start.

```
 var csvs = new List<string>();  

csvs.Add( "Company Name 1,123 Main St."); 
 csvs.Add("Company Name 2,1 Elm St.,2 Elm St."); 

 var xml = 
 (from c in csvs 
 let split = c.Split(',')
 select  // split
 new XElement("ArrayOfBusiness", 
    new XElement("Business", 
        new XElement("Name", split[0] ), 
        new XElement("AddressList", 
          new XElement("Address"
            ,
            (from s in split.Skip(1) // skip the first split 
            select 
            new XElement("AddressLine", s)) 
        )
 )))); // <-- is it LISP? 

 xml.Dump();
```

Results:

```
<ArrayOfBusiness>
  <Business>
    <Name>Company Name 1</Name>
    <AddressList>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine>123 Main St.</AddressLine>
      </Address>
    </AddressList>
  </Business>
  <Business>
    <Name>Company Name 2</Name>
    <AddressList>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine>1 Elm St.</AddressLine>
        <AddressLine>2 Elm St.</AddressLine>
      </Address>
    </AddressList>
  </Business>
</ArrayOfBusiness>
```

It isn't exactly what you wanted, but looks functionally equivalent to me. Might need a bit of tweaking in the LINQ.

Write to file with: `File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\addresses.xml", xml.ToString());`

Comment: There's room for error handling in here, what if the AddressList is empty etc.

Comment: Will it work the other way around? I want to produce the xml from a spreadsheet/csv file.

Comment: how do I get the results into an .xml file?

Comment: I'm getting this in the file:
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.String,System.Xml.Linq.XElement]

Comment: @rod: that means you're getting multiple elements in a place where you're expecting 1. So you'll need to do a First() in that portion of the linq query. I suspect you're adding in more xml and seeing odd results so it'll take a little tweaking. Note that in LINQPad you can put a .Dump() method behind just about anything so you can see what's happening in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the .csv file into 'Business' objects should be straightforward.

Its then a simple case of using the XmlSerializer class to generate the xml.

Comment: And how is this Business Object gonna look like? CSV is flat. XML is hierarchical. No 1 to 1 mapping possible unless of course you hard-code it somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. If the data is stored in csv format then the data is flat. Therefore the fact that xml is hierarchical is irrelevant as it can still store flat data.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, but with out seeing the CSV file it is hard to say.

If your CSV was somthing like this:

> Name, Address1, Address2
>
> Company Name 1,123 Main St.,
>
> Company Name 2,1 Elm St.,1 Elm St.

you could easily parse this into a class.

```
class Business
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Address> AddressList { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
  public string AddressLine { get; set; }
}
```

(untested)